# CSS Specificity for transparent and none border

Tags: css

I'm styling the page which has consecutive boxes with bottom border except for the last box. I applied class `.box` for all the boxes and added `.box_last` to hide the border only for the last box.

```css
.box {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.box_last {
  border-bottom-style: transparent;
}
```

However, I realized that the browser is still applying my `.box` styling. But when I changed the `.box_last` from `transparent` to `none`, the browser overrode the first style and the border is disappeared.

I have searched for a few CSS specificity articles but hasn't got the answer yet. Can anyone explain for me? Thanks in advances.

Comment: transparent is `color`, not `style`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `border-bottom-style: transparent;` is not working is because `transparent` is a color, not a style. This should work fine:

```
.box_last {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

Or without an extra class:

```
.box:last-child {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Can you please accept my answer on the left? Thanks!